# JEP 323 Where is @Notnull in java-11

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-11

I started Java 11 yesterday, I downloaded the JDK , made to Environment variables of PC(windows),
created a new project and set up the JDK and JRE to point to the Java 11.

I even checked my Env Variables again by `echo %JAVA_HOME%` in cmd , it is fine.

Every things seems ok but my compiler is not recognizing `@Notnull var` , can someone help!

Basic program i am trying to execute:

```
                 list.stream()
                .map((@Notnull var s) -> s.toLowerCase())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Error is:**

```
Error:(13, 24) java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   class Notnull
location: class Main
```

> Have even changed the language level in **Project structure** by
>   `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S` to `X-Experimental features`  , but nothing helps.
>
> Tried checking `import  java.lang.*;` and found that `@Notnull` is not
>   there too.

Comment: Did you mean `@NotNull` (camelCased?) What error message are you getting?

Comment: Where is this annotation defined? Do you need to add a JAR file for it? Do you have the `import` statement for it?

Comment: It has to be imported from somewhere, there is no `Notnull` in `java.lang` package.

Comment: I am sure there are many pro people using `java 11` now.

Comment: Just to pitch in with a guess, while the JEP was proposed/written the annotations might have been a part of `rt.jar.` The package they belong to would have been in that case `javax.annotation.*`. Now that it's no more a part of the native JDK, you wouldn't be able to resolve them without including a dependency for e.g. `<dependency> <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId> <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId> <version>1.3.2</version> </dependency>`. Considering the code in the [JEP-323](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/323) and the JEP uses `@Nonnull`

Comment: So where did you get this source code from? Where did you use `@Notnull` before?

Comment: [Here is an alphabetized list of all classes in Java SE 11.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/allclasses.html)  As you can see, there is no class named `Notnull`, or `NotNull`, or `NonNull`.  The use of “@Nonnull” in JEP 323’s text is just an example of how a theoretical annotation might be used.

Comment: That article was just showing an example for the new syntax to use an annotation on the lamdba parameter. It is not about an actual annotation (although it would have been nice of them to use on that exists/works).

Comment: I think intellij tag should be removed.

Answer (score 5):

JEP 323 provides the syntax to use annotations on lambda parameters.

There is no class named `Notnull`, or `NotNull`, or `NonNull`. The use of “`@Nonnull`” in JEP 323’s text is just an example of how a theoretical annotation might be used.